# how to extract a json object using swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

JSON function:

```
func extract_json(data:NSString){

    var parseError: NSError?

    let jsonData:NSData = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!


  let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &parseError)

    if (parseError == nil){

        if let coupon_list = json as? [String: AnyObject]{

            if let coupons = coupon_list["data"] as? [AnyObject]{

                for (var i = 0; i < coupons.count ; i++ ){

                    if let coupon_obj = coupons[i] as? NSDictionary{

                        let location: AnyObject? = coupon_obj.objectForKey("location")

                     //the print the value location
                     println(location)
```

//I just want to get the number keys before the value of the location 
this is my Json object where you can see that

```
{
brand = "Mang Inasal";
category =     (
    2
);
desc = "Mang Inasal Salmonella Giveaway";
discount = 50;
"end_date" = 1443369600;
id = 2;
imgs =     (
    "http://mymegamobile.com/savvy/halo2x.png",
    "http://mymegamobile.com/savvy/bar_filter.png",
    "http://mymegamobile.com/savvy/bar_mega.png",
    "http://mymegamobile.com/savvy/box1.png",
    "http://mymegamobile.com/savvy/box2.png"
);
location =     {
    1435307555 = Baguio;
};
name = "Mang Inasal Halo Halo";
stamp = "2015-09-02 14:04:38";
"start_date" = 1438012800;
}
```

the result of the object structure is above.
How can I get the value of `1435307555` in my location?

Comment: "in a object json parse swift iOS?" – *what?*

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
let yourObject = location?.objectForKey("165952298") as! String
```

Comment: i mean i need to get the exact 165952298 when I'm using this code let location = coupon_obj["location"] the return value is only the name antipolo i need to get the value 165952298

Comment: Can you explain it with example in your question?

Comment: Dharmesh thanks for the effort i really appreciate it. by the way  the value 165952298 is the value that i need to get. from my object coupon_obj["location"]

Comment: i post the structure of the object i get in the json hope to understand my question

Answer (score 0):

```
for (key,value) in coupon_list {
    println(key)
}
```

This way you'll get all keys from the JSON

Comment: see my new post sir i need to get the key value in the location

Answer (score 0):

```
func extract_json(data:NSString){

 var parseError: NSError?

 let jsonData:NSData = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!


 let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &parseError) as! NSDictionary

   if (parseError == nil) { 

              for (var i = 0; i < json.count ; i++ ) { 

                    let location: AnyObject? = ((json)["location"] as! NSDictionary)["1435307555"]

                 //the print the value location
                 println(location)

              }


   }
```